# Не получается совладать с session()

Tags: php, html, сессия

Как  можно написать logout выход с сессии в этом же коде?Чтобы при нажатии на картинку выходило из сессии типа unset и destroy (не используя подключения нового файла)

```
?session_start();
     if ($_SESSION["Login"] != "YES") {
      include 'steam_auth.php';
    }


      else {
тут ваш код
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Картинку заключите в ссылку с параметром logout

```
<a href="/?logout=1"><img src="logout-img.gif" /></a>
```

Затем в коде пропишите условие

```
if ($_GET['logout']) {
    session_destroy();
}
```

При нажатии на картинку получится нужный эффект.